# Can't reference object properties after navigating to new page (C#, Xamarin)

Tags: c#, database, xamarin

I am having trouble referencing some properties from my recipe object (that references an InventoryItem object (or ingredient)). First, here are the classes.

```
public class InventoryItem
{
    [PrimaryKey]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Size { get; set; }
    public string Stock { get; set; }
}

public class Recipe
{
    [PrimaryKey]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [OneToOne]
    public InventoryItem Ingredient { get; set; }
}
```

Next, this is the code that creates a new recipe and sets the Ingredient property to inventoryItem. (inventoryItem has already been instantiated and sets each property for the Ingredient correctly.)

```
        Recipe recipe = new Recipe()
        {
            ID = (maxPK == null ? 1 : maxPK.ID + 1),
            Name = nameEntry.Text,
            Ingredient = inventoryItem
        };
```

Lastly, here I just wanted to test that this recipe ingredient was set properly, so I check and the recipe.Ingredient.Name does pop up **correctly**.

```
        db.Insert(recipe);
        await DisplayAlert(null, recipe.Name + " - " + recipe.Ingredient.Name + " saved!", "okay.");
        await Navigation.PopAsync();
```

Now for the issue... First, I send the selected/specified recipe as a reference when I open a new ViewRecipePage. The specified recipe is selected from a collectionView of all Recipes.

```
    private async void checkRecipe_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        await Navigation.PushAsync(new ViewRecipePage(recipe));
    }
```

Then on the ViewRecipePage I want to view different properties of that recipe, including the Ingredient, of course.

```
        try
        {
            Label recipeName = new Label();
            recipeName.Text = recipe.Name;
            grid.Children.Add(recipeName);

            Label ingredient1Name = new Label();
            ingredient1Name.Text = recipe.Ingredient.Name;
            grid.Children.Add(ingredient1Name);

        }catch(Exception e) {  DisplayAlert(null, e.ToString(), "okay."); };
```

The recipe.Name shows up fine, however, whenever I try to reference the recipe.Ingredient.Name in any way, I get the error "System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

I'm sure it's something stupid I missed somewhere along the way, but I can't figure out why this is when I tested that the recipe.Ingredient.Name works when I added the recipe to the database...

Anyway, let me know if there is more information I can provide! Thanks for taking a look! Cheers.

EDIT:

New Recipe class with OneToMany for ingredients

```
public class Recipe
{
    [PrimaryKey]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [OneToMany("ID")]
    public List<InventoryItem> Ingredient { get; set; }
}
```

Now when adding a new recipe, I create a list for the ingredients, then set the Ingredients List to that new list...

```
        inventoryItem = (InventoryItem)ingredient1Picker.SelectedItem;
        List<InventoryItem> invList = new List<InventoryItem>();
        invList.Add(inventoryItem);

        Recipe recipe = new Recipe()
        {
            ID = (maxPK == null ? 1 : maxPK.ID + 1),
            Name = nameEntry.Text,
            Ingredient = invList    
        };
```

Then I insert into the database and check to see the Ingredient was set - this all works fine.

```
        db.Insert(recipe);
        await DisplayAlert(null, recipe.Name + recipe.Ingredient[0].Name + " saved!", "okay.");
```

However, on my "GetRecipesPage," I source the collectionView like this:

```
        collectionView.ItemsSource = db.GetAllWithChildren<Recipe>().OrderBy(x => x.Name).ToList();
```

However, when I select a recipe and navigate to ViewRecipePage and try to display the Ingredients list (I just try to see the first and only ingredient in the list), I get the error Index was out of range. Which I assume means that the list isn't populated at all, even after I set the Ingredients list of the recipe to a list with an ingredient in it and tested it.

```
        try
        {
            Label recipeName = new Label();
            recipeName.Text = recipe.Name;
            grid.Children.Add(recipeName);

            Label ingredient1Name = new Label();
            ingredient1Name.Text = recipe.Ingredient[0].Name;
            grid.Children.Add(ingredient1Name);

        }catch(Exception e) {  DisplayAlert(null, e.ToString(), "okay."); };
```

Comment: how are you populating your CollectionView?  Are you sure the query you are using is also including the child objects?

Comment: I am not sure it is including child objects...               

collectionView.ItemsSource = db.Table<Recipe>().OrderBy(x =>x.Name).ToList();                

Now that I am looking at that, I am assuming it is not, but I also don't know how hahah.

Comment: ...I have no idea how to format on this site, sorry lol.

Comment: if you are using the sqlite.net extensions, try `GetWithChildren`

Comment: I'm going to edit my question so you can see the changes I've made and I can explain the new errors with more clarity.

Comment: are you sure your child data is getting saved to the db?  Have you examined the results of the GetWithChildren in the debugger to see if it includes the child objects?

Comment: Right, I see. The child data is NOT getting saved to the db. Why would that be? If I created the recipe object with the Ingredients set to a list I don't understand why that data wouldn't be saved with it. Unless my keys are set up incorrectly? I am TERRIBLE with databases.

Comment: InsertWithChildren.  Docs here: https://bitbucket.org/twincoders/sqlite-net-extensions/src/master/

Comment: Jason... you are a hero. Can I mark a comment as the answer? Thank you so much, and thanks for the documentation!

I'll probably have another problem tomorrow and you can solve that one too ;) Haha, thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you are using SQLite Extensions, you need to be sure that you are using `InsertWithChildren` and `GetWithChildren` when dealing with child tables/objects.